# Sample easy project with good template in django as provided in web2py

Tags: django

I have started learning Django and have completed the tutorial provided at Django site. I also ran the tutorial present for Web2py but I want to continue with django. But problem I am facing is that Django doesn't creates a sample app just like web2py does on new project creation which provides a good look and feel on project.

Can some one please point me to a simple and small template in Django that I can use for my sample applications in Django. I have searched the [Djangosites.org](http://www.djangosites.org/with-source) but they are too complex for begineer. I am looking for a html template just like sample web2py appliance provides.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [django-sample-app](https://github.com/kirpit/django-sample-app) can help you.